# How to create procedurally generated surface bubbles on a liquid

Tags: modeling, materials, node-editor

I am trying to procedurally generated surface bubbles on coffee. I know that you can use a UV map to do this, but I'd like to have more control. There is a nice demo of doing this with animation is 3ds Max, but I haven't worked out a way to do it in Blender.

http://www.3dtotal.com/tutorial/1878-creating-and-animating-bubbles-3ds-max-misc-by-alvaro-moreira-particle-flow-frost

I have tried using metaballs, but without much success. Here is the look I'd like simulate.

[image]

Comment: Maybe some ideas - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52834/creating-a-liquid-bubble-effect. It looks like more complicated here though as bubbles should be formed with 2 surfaces, water and wall.

Comment: I did see that and tried playing with the metaballs. Just couldn't get very useful results.  Also tried this Metaballs as Dew Drops tutorial from Sardi Pax. 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5If5IFVK1cU

Comment: UV map +  particle system + metaballs will work

Comment: Thanks eromod. I do know that a UV map will work, it is what I am using now. Metaballs and the particle system will work too. I even mentioned UV and Metaballs in the question and included links. I just don't have the skills yet to get the results I'd like and am looking for some useful guidance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The new microdisplacment feature can help with that. Here is a simple node setup as a proof of concept:
[image: node setup]
[image: render result]

After duplicating this effect a couple of time you can obtain that:

[image]

Comment: nice idea! +1 well deserved.

Comment: would be nice to get a bit more insight on how to 'duplicate the effect a couple of times', and also to mention in detail how to use the microdisplacement (set to experimental, add a subsurf, tweak it, and set displacement to 'True' in the material)

Comment: Thanks Vanitat. That looks very good. I will give it a try.

Comment: how did you make the smaller bubbles on the second image be only around the bigger one's?

Comment: @aliasguru, Hi, I am new to blender and have struggled to do this approach, currently I have finally achieved the bubble look, though I had to add a Vector node before connecting to the final displacement. However, I cannot understand how they managed to make the final image, I have been tweaking the Voronoi texture but cannot make it so the high values go to the perimeter only, how was this achieved?

Comment: Since the original respondent doesn't seem to be present here anymore and refused to give more information on how to achieve the result in the bottom picture: can anybody explain how to do this? Because when I try to recreate the shown node setup with recent Blender versions I hardly get close to the result on top - and I have no idea how to "duplicate this effect a couple of times" to come to the bottom result. @DanaWilliams Have you ever reached this effect?

Answer (score 3):

Since people have been asking how to blend the nodes together like in the example above here is one way to do it.

[image: Node group]

Make the white part of the color ramp darker grey depending on the scale of the bubbles (voronoi) to adjust their height then blend them with a color mix set to lighten.

The second color ramp from the original example controls how many (or how dense) you want the bubbles to be.

[image: Bubbles]

To get a flat area your best bet is to add a white image texture and mix it in with a color mix set to darken, then go into texture paint and use a black brush to paint out the bubbles you don't want. Obviously the more effort you put into this step the better it will look. I was sloppy here but you can see it works pretty well.

[image]