# bump-mapping or something else?

Tags: modeling

Maybe you guys can point me in the right direction. I want to create glass vase and have on it something like on the picture below (random pushed dots?) but I cant do this in Solidworks. So I was thinking to export stl file to Blender and do this in it. What is the best way to do it? Will appreciate any help. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Does this help ? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58493/how-to-create-procedurally-generated-surface-bubbles-on-a-liquid

Comment: I will check it out. Thanks

Comment: Do you need to 3D print this? .i.e. Do you want the displacement in the geometry, as well as the render?