# How do you create procedural bubbles on a surface?

Tags: materials, shaders, displacement, procedural

I'm trying to achieve the answer in [How to create procedurally generated surface bubbles on a liquid](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58493/how-to-create-procedurally-generated-surface-bubbles-on-a-liquid.But) I'm unsure on how to do this in 2.9.

Comment: I think this should still work, though I might mention that actual displacement only works in Cycles when such is set to “Displacement only” or “Displacement and bump” and not “Bump only,” and what’s more it does not generate new geometry: The plane in question has to be deeply subdivided for this to work correctly.

Comment: On the other hand, geometry nodes might be a better way to do this whole idea fluently and with less unused vertices.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks for the help

Comment: The linked answer doesn't need much subdivision since it's working with microdisplacement... actually it works on a plane with only 4 vertices. However, I would really like to achieve that look but as others there are pointing out in the comments, a little more info would have been useful. With the node setup pictured there somehow translated to an updated version I get something that looks (kind of) the top image, but I don't know how to get to the bottom result from there. It's a pity the original respondent never answered that.

Comment: @Gordon The setup seems to still work. The Voronoi node changed a bit, you need to add a *Multiply* node to get the same output :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a setup for both large and tiny bubbles :-)

1. Create a plane or a subdivided circle
2. Enable Adaptive Subdivision to use microdisplacement
3. Set Material Displacement > Displacement (only works in Cycles)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: "Minor tweaks", that's good... you're funny :D Multiplying the _Voronoi_ textures with themselves, then subtracting one from the other, no power node, combining with _Musgrave_ texture... that's almost a completely different setup ;) Or at least, from what is shown in the original setup which only needs to be "duplicated a couple of times" as stated there, I would have never come to your node setup. Thanks! I'll try that.

Comment: I now realize it's actually quite more complex :). Anyways, it works and that's the point.

Comment: That's really cool. The only thing I changed from this setup: some bubbles (especially visible on the larger ones) have quite sharp ridges or at least the shading isn't so smooth in some parts because of the _Musgrave_ texture's _Color Ramp_. So I've set the white slider completely back to the right end. And if I want to increase the gaps between the bubbles I multiply the ramp output by a factor > 1. This makes the bubbles look smoother.

Comment: Good idea, that bothered me a bit too, thx :)